# Kotlin sequences: filter + find first + map

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, sequence

In Java streams API i can make something like this:

```
someStream.stream()
          .filter(someCondition)
          .findFirst()
          .map(someMappingStatement)
          .orElse(null)
```

And i wan't to do the same code with sequences:

```
someSequence.asSequence()
            .filter{ someCondition }
            .map{ someMappingStatement }
            .firstOrNull()
```

I have some worries about `findFirst()`. Because in sequences here i filter, then map all, but not first element. How can i rewrite it better in sequences?

Comment: Kotlin sequences are lazily evaluated, like Java streams. That doesn't apply to Kotlin lists, so in that case you'd first apply `filter` on all items, then `map` all the items passing the filtering step, and finally you'd only take the first item out of the resulting list.

Comment: *here I filter, then map all, but not first element* that is not correct, since you are using Sequence after filter get element only 1 map operation and then get the first element. Here you can find details https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-stream-vs-kotlin#lazy-sequences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it doesn't matter which order these two operations occur. You could swap `firstOrNull` and `map` by replacing `map` with `let`, but there wouldn't be any significant difference in computation time, specifically because you're working with a Sequence rather than a List. With a Sequence, the fact that you use `firstOrNull` as your terminal operation means that the `map` function will only be run on that first element.

Comment: So, filter and map will be processed on element a[i] and then move to element a[i + 1[, correct?

Comment: @SlandShow Only one map then `firstOrNull` terminal operation that's all.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of using a Sequence, to avoid unnecessary intermediate actions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but in case of streams vs sequences there is no such performance difference. Because both api's use lazy evaluation. So, why sequences is better? Because of more clean api functions and operators?

Comment: Who said it’s better? I think it mostly exists because Streams aren’t available on JDK 6 and 7 or in JS. Although you might prefer the sequence api functions. Their naming more closely follows the Iterator functions.